# Python Requests throwing SSLError after downloading certificate

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am using the requests.get() command from the requests package but am getting the following error indicating I believe that I am not verifying the SSL connection properly.

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='marketplace.spp.org', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url:
> /file-browser-api/download/da-lmp-by-location?path=%2F2020%2F08%2FBy_Day%2FDA-LMP-SL-202008020100.csv
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib
> (_ssl.c:3524)'),))

Here are the ways I have tried using requests.get(). I tried them each individually, but they all returned the same error.

```
url = 'https://marketplace.spp.org/file-browser-api/download/da-lmp-by-location?path=%2F{}%2F{:02}%2FBy_Day%2FDA-LMP-SL-{}{:02}{:02}0100.csv'.format(year, month, year, month, day)
r = requests.get(url)
r = requests.get(url, cert='spp_cert.crt')
r = requests.get(url, verify='spp_cert.crt')
r = requests.get(url, verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt')
```

Note that I have retrieved the cert 'spp_cert.crt' by running the command

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername marketplace.spp.org -connect marketplace.spp.org:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > spp_cert.crt
```

I believe the location **/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt** is where my CA bundle is located as I ran the following command from the bash command line to figure it out.

```
python3 -m certifi
```

I want to note I have been using **verify=False** as the argument, but as the code is evolving from a throwaway to production, I no longer want to ignore this warning. I'll admit I get a little confused on how SSL certificates and verification work, and this is probably the source of my problem.

Lastly, I want to note that I was able to download the identical certificate through Firefox, but noticed it had two options to download the certificate (PEM (cert) PEM (chain)), and I have a hunch the problem is I need to download the certificate chain instead of just one certificate. But I don't really know how this works, if this is even what I need to do, and if it is what I need to do, how to do so with **openssl**. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed that I needed to download the certificate chain, and not just the individual certificate. I do not know how to do this with **openssl** as I would like, but I was able to do it in Firefox.

This is done by going to the website, clicking on the padlock next to the web address, clicking on the arrow next to the message "Connection secure", clicking "More Information", going to the "Security" tab, clicking on "View Certificate", then clicking on the download "PEM (chain)" in the "Miscellaneous" section. This is the certificate I needed to make **requests.get()** work properly.